# Bittorrent Sync upload/download rate limit not working

Tags: networking, sync, bittorrent

I am happily using BitTorrent Sync but I can't limit its upload/download rate.

If I click on the Preferences Gear --> Advanced I can set "Limit receiving rate" and "Limit sending rate".

I do this, restart the program and nothing happens: it keeps on downloading eating the whole bandwidth...

I use it on Windows Server 2008.

What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you syncing on your local network? At least on the Linux implementations, btsync does not enforce rate limiting by default on LAN.

Answer (score 0):

If on the same network, check that the "rate_limit_local_peers" is set to true.

This applies    speed limits to the peers   in  local   network.    By  default the limits
are not applied in  LAN.

The setting for windows is under prefernces -> advanced tab -> more options.

[image]

Comment: This really isn't worthy of a full answer, so can you expand upon this? If not, consider deleting this answer and reposting this as a comment to the question.

Comment: I don't have that parameter in the gui

Comment: @Pitto I version2.x GUI I have to goto into settings -> advanced -> more options.  In the linux version I have to enable it in the configuration file. Are you syncing two machines on the same network though?

Answer (score 0):

As Matt answered (I really dont understand why he was downvoted), the solution of this question is set the rate_limit_local_peers variable to true in Advanced Preference tab as showed below. By default, btsync behavior not limits bandwidth consume for local sync. For more information, see http://sync-help.bittorrent.com/customer/portal/articles/1670248-advanced-preferences?b_id=3885 and control+F for rate_limit_local_peers